# Dynamically modifying the HighChart layout options

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I can't find way to update marginTop value of already created chart.

Check out my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/TZaEV/4/

```
var btn = $('#btn');
btn.click(function(){
// do changes
});
```

I need to change chart.marginTop value without creating chart object again. (When I click on trigger button, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var btn = $('#btn');
btn.click(function(){
    chart.optionsMarginTop += 20;
    chart.isDirtyBox = true; // this makes your chart redraw
    chart.redraw();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TZaEV/7/)

Comment: Yes, that's it! Nice properties :) (isDirtyBox and isDirtyLegend)

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
const chart = $("#container").highcharts();
chart.options.chart.marginTop = 100;
chart.isDirtyBox = true;
chart.redraw();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using Chart.update() function?

```
chart.update({
  chart: {
    marginTop: 30
  }
});
```

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.update
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginTop

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/neo0xb2w/